# How to use <select> of flask-wtf in jinjia2?

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I want to display the "category" of one data in the html "select" field.
The data comes from view.py and the category of the data is "category2".
I use jinjia2 to display html:

```
render_temperlate(data=data,form=form,'data.html')
```

Then I define a flask-wtf SelectField in the form.py  like this：

```
Class  CategoryForm(FlaskForm):
    category = SelectField(choices=[('','') , ("category 1","category 1"),("category2","category2")])
```

Now, I want to display the category of my data (It's values is "capetory2") in the web html "select" tag.

In the data.html file(jinjia2)，I try to use

```
{{form.category(option=data.category)}}
```

to display the data's category(category2)， but in the web，the  field has nothing.

What should I do？

Answer (score -1):

If value is passed to form on creation it would be selected in a HTML form after rendering, you don't need pass it as an option.

```
import flask
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from jinja2 import Template
from wtforms import SelectField

class CategoryForm(FlaskForm):
    category = SelectField(choices=[('','') , ("category 1","category 1"),("category 2","category 2")])

    class Meta:
        csrf = False

def index():
    cf = CategoryForm(category="category 1")
    return flask.render_template(
        Template("""
                <html>
                <body>
                    <form method="POST">
                        {{form.category()}}
                        <input type="submit">
                    </form>
                </body>
                </html>
                """),
        form=cf)
```

Comment: Thanks. In my data.html there are ten rows in a table like:
"<table><tr><td>row1</td><select><option></option></select></tr>
<tr><td>row2</td><select><option></option></select></tr>
<tr><td>row3</td><select><option></option></select></tr>
...</table>"

How should I pass the form.category.data to every "select" field disposabled?

Comment: I don't know HTML so well and don't understand your question. I think it'd be better if you start a separate question for someone else to answer.

Comment: I have solved the problem by jquery already. Thanks all.
The back-end pass the select value to jinja2 , then use jquery to compare the value with the select option value ,if the option value is same as the passed value, then add an attribute named "selected" to the option.So, the select field can display the category of the data in the web page.